# How to add WAI-ARIA dynamically in asp.net Validation controls?

Tags: asp.net, validation, webforms, accessibility, wai-aria

I have ASP.NET Web forms and there are a few asp.net validation controls like RequiredFieldValidator, RegularExpresionValidator etc. used. I have to make the form accessible so that screen readers can read the screen properly. I have to add WAI-ARIA attributes **'role'='alert'** and **'aria-atomic':'true'** to the respective validation control if there is any validation failure and those attribute shouldn't be there if validation is passed. But I am wondering how to add these attributes and I need some help to add WAI-ARIA into the validation controls. My Web Form HTML is as below:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="Fileupload" runat="server" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server"
 ErrorMessage="Please select a zip file to upload!!!"
 ControlToValidate="Fileupload" ForeColor="Red" Display="Dynamic" >
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" 
  ErrorMessage="Only zip file is allowed!!!" ForeColor="Red" 
  ValidationExpression="^.+(.zip|.ZIP)$" ControlToValidate="Fileupload" 
   Display="Dynamic"> </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add it to a Validator like this

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" WAI-ARIA="'role'='alert'"
```

The generated html looks like this

```
<span id="RequiredFieldValidator1" wai-aria="'role'='alert'">Please select .. </span>
```

Comment: I am using NVDA screen reader and the way you approached is not working for me as the screen reader is unable to read validation error message.

Comment: Then you should figure out why it does not read them since the `wai-aria` attribute is present in the HTML. Can it not read span? or elements that are shown with javascript?

Comment: When I click on a submit button, I can see the validation message but the NVDA didn't read anything. If there's a working sample, that would be a lot of help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to do it for your exact use case, but here's an example where I needed to add `aria-describedby` to a custom control--in my case a radio button.  I created a new class and added a property that sets the attribute:

```
public class Bootstrap4RadioButton : RadioButton
{
    public Bootstrap4RadioButton()
    {
        this.InputAttributes.Add("class", "form-check-input");
        this.LabelAttributes.Add("class", "form-check-label");
        this.Attributes.Add("class", "form-check");
        this.AutoPostBack = true;
    }

    public string AriaDescribedBy
    {
        set
        {
            this.InputAttributes["aria-describedby"] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Then when creating the control, I add `AriaDescribedBy="feedback"` like a regular control property:

```
<mc:Bootstrap4RadioButton ID="other" runat="server"
    Text="Other issue/question"
    GroupName="reason"
    OnCheckedChanged="other_CheckedChanged"
    AriaDescribedBy="feedback"></mc:Bootstrap4RadioButton>
```

This is how it renders in the browser:

```
<input id="MainContent_other" 
    type="radio" 
    name="ctl00$MainContent$reason" 
    value="other" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$MainContent$other\',\'\')', 0)" 
    class="form-check-input" 
    aria-describedby="feedback">
```